# Combining SQL Server stored procedure WITH LOCK and INNER JOIN using passed in list of strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a SQL procedure that I can pass a list of strings and return something only if there is an existing result and combine it the with lock statement. I'm using a User Defined Table Type to pass in the list of strings but I haven't worked with procedures that much and I'm getting errors that I will post below. I'm using EF 6 with C# on a Database first code application. Here is the code that I'm trying to do and how I want to call it in the C# code:

```
CREATE TYPE TaskTable 
AS TABLE ( Name VARCHAR(7) );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DequeuePending]
    @tasklist TaskTable READONLY
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @now AS DATETIME;
    SET @now = getutcdate();

    WITH cte AS   
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) Task
        FROM InProgresses 
        INNER JOIN @tasklist ON InProgresses.Task = @tasklist.Name WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
        WHERE Date < @now && InProgresses.Task IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY Date
    )
    DELETE cte
    OUTPUT deleted.Task;
GO
```

I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable @tasklist

C# code:

```
var taskList = new List<string>() { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" };
using var context = new dbconfig();
var topItem = context.DequeuePending(taskList);
```

I tried doing a DECLARE @list as TaskTable; and received the same error so I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Table hint should be after, well, table name/alias ... Also it's unclear if you are getting this with create or execute statement... If create then c# tag is unrelated

Comment: You want `FROM InProgresses WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST) INNER JOIN @tasklist AS t ON InProgresses.Task = t.Name` Must say: creative use of `READPAST` and `OUTPUT`, to implement a concurrent queue. Incidentally you can do a `DELETE TOP (1)`. You may want to loop it if you get no result, which could happen in the event of every row being locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON InProgresses.Task = @tasklist.Name`

I feel like it has something to do with this line.

```
INNER JOIN @tasklist tl
      ON InProgresses.Task = tl.Name
```

Normally I'd assign the table in question an alias so that I can reference it later in the query. I'm not supremely familiar with user defined table types so if the above suggestion doesn't work, maybe just doing a straight select from that table to see if everything is working correctly there.